# Clean way to map objects to other objects?

Tags: typescript, casting, typing

Is there a good way to map objects to other objects? Library recommendations welcome too.

For example, say I have these classes:

```
export class Draft {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    summary: string;
}

export class Book {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    info: Info;
}

export class Info {
    value: string;
}
```

Traditionally, to map fields from `Draft` to `Book` I'd have to do so manually for each field:

```
export class Book {
    [...]

    fromDraft(Draft draft) {
        this.id = draft.id;
        this.name = draft.name;
        this.info = new Info();
        this.info.value = draft.summary;
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to map object fields that are named the same way? For example `Draft` and `Book`'s `id` and `name` fields, while also being able to define custom mappings, like from `draft.summary` to `book.info.value`.

Note that this is far from my actual use case. Here it's not so bad to do assignments manually, but for objects with many similarly named fields it's quite a chore.

Thanks!

Comment: Really not sure what your question mean, but can you not simply abstract both `Book` and `Draft` into a more generic parent class that shares the common fields, and `extend` from that parent class? Alternatively, you can use [decorators](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/).

Comment: That could be an option, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of TypeScript, you can use lodash [`_.mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) and pass your merge function.

**Advantage:** More generic (If you have more logic you can add it (for complex types for example)

**Disadvantage**: You need lodash

Something like:

```js
var a = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3],
  bar: true
}

var b = {
  foo: [4, 5, 6, 7],
  bar: false
}

var c = _.mergeWith(a, b, function(a, b) {
  if (a.concat) {
    return a.concat(b);
  }
  else {
    return b;
  }
})

console.log('c', c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsbin.com/xugujon/edit?html,js

Comment: Interesting library, thank you! This is actually exactly the kind of mapper/merger I was thinking of!

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!

Comment: How to handle cases where the property names differ ?  Does mergeWith has ways to handle it ?

Comment: @Dibzmania I'm not sure I understand. Can you post a link to an example code?

Answer (score 3):

With regards to copying properties of the same name, you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
fromDraft(Draft draft) {
    Object.assign(this, draft);
    this.info = new Info();
    this.info.value = draft.summary;
}
```

The problem is that it will also create `this.summary`, but it's a convenient way of copying properties so if you can model your classes differently then you can use it.

Another option is to have a list of shared property names and then iterate it:

```
const SHARED_NAMES = ["id", "name"];

fromDraft(Draft draft) {
    SHARED_NAMES.forEach(name => this[name] = draft[name]);
    this.info = new Info();
    this.info.value = draft.summary;
}
```