# Concat two objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dictionary, concatenation

I have two objects with the same properties but holding different values

EXAMPLE:

```
export class obj1{
  arr1: values[]
  dic1: { [key: string]: Value; };
  bool1: boolean
}
export class obj2{
  arr1: values[]
  dic1: { [key: string]: Value; };
  bool1: boolean
}
```

Where the property of the object is an array or dictionary I want obj2 values to add to the values of obj1. Where there are boolean\string\number properties I want obj2 properties to replace obj1

Is there a clean way of doing this in a few lines or will I have to map every property.

Comment: Try this maybe if its arrays. `var newobj = Object.assign(obj1, obj2);`

Comment: You can use lodash [`_.mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) and pass your function. See this: http://jsbin.com/xugujon/edit?html,js

Comment: Deckerz unfortunately that replaces all the properties with the same name, it doesn't add to arrays and dictionaries

Comment: You should give a real example (that's what examples are for).  Your example contains syntax errors.  And tell us what result you expect.  I'm not sure if you want/need a recursive function.  I would if I saw an example.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153228/clean-way-to-map-objects-to-other-objects).

Basically:

Since your two classes have the same properties, you could just have them extend the same class. Then you could write a method for the class itself called "merge()" or something that maps the properties manually, which shouldn't actually look that complicated.

**Edit:**

Something similar to this, but you might still need separate classes for your use case. **Edit:** For merging dictionaries added the logic.

```
export class obj {
  arr1: values[]
  dic1: { [key: string]: Value; };
  bool1: boolean


  merge(otherObj : obj) {
    let newObj:obj;
    newObj.arr1 = this.arr1.concat(otherObj.arr1);
    newObj.dic1 = {};
    newObj.dic1 = Object.assign(newObj.dic1, this.dic1);
    newObj.dic1 = Object.assign(newObj.dic1, otherObj.dic1);
    newObj.bool1 = this.otherObj.bool1;
    return newObj;
  }
}
```

See:

[How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Wouldn't this newObj.dic1 = this.otherObj.dic1; replace newObj.dic1 with otherObj.dic1? How would you add to the first dictionary

Comment: @RichardWatts Yeah that's what I don't understand from your question, do you have an example of how you want these two dictionaries to be merged? I'm guessing you want all the key/value pairs to be all put into one dictionary, but what if the keys are the same on two objects?

Comment: Good point mintychai. The two dictionaries will never have the same keys. I do want the key\value pairs to be all put into one dictionary

Comment: @RichardWatts Merging dictionaries is pretty easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically Added to the answer!

Comment: from what I can see the solution in that post would overwrite values where the properties match. I want to merge so I maintain all values

Comment: I thought you said they never have the same keys?